# getting the distance between two location on iphone

Tags: iphone

i am trying to calculate the distance between the statringpoint which hold the initial value of location and the newlocation using the following code but i am getting null in distance. can anyone help me out with this

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:startingPoint];
```

Comment: are newLocation and startingPoint both of type: CLLocation *?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. Maybe **startingPoint** is *nil*?